# Running PHP inside of PHP echo?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I just found out that you can't run PHP inside of a PHP echo (yes silly of me)
So I can't think of an alternative way to run this script, perhaps making a variable?

It's a wordpress php script within a php script

```
<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { 
echo '<a href=" <?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/login" class="typcn typcn-key-outline">Log in</a>';
}
else {
echo '<a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-login.php?action=logout" class="typcn typcn-key-outline">Log out</a>';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, there are few mistakes in this script.

First of all, you are using php tags inside php tags, it doesn't make sense, you are already using php so you don't need those php tags.

But even if you remove the php tags it won't work because you are inside a string, so you are asking php to write litteraly get_site_url() (you are not calling get_site_url(), you are litteraly writing get_site_url())

What should you do then ?

Lets see how concatenation work first. The concatenation operator is ".". It allows to concatenate two string.

Example :

```
 $sentence = "Hello" . " " . "Thierry"; // means $sentence = "Hello Thierry".
```

Okay now lets do the same with variable.

```
$name = "Thierry";
$sentence = "Hello" . " " . $name; // means $sentence = "Hello Thierry";
```

This is everything you need here.

Lets see how we can solve your problem then,

what you want as a result is :

```
echo '<a href="yourSiteUrl/login" class="typcn typcn-key-outline">Log in</a>';
```

Now we replace yourSiteUrl with the concatenation operator and the php function. And you have :

```
echo '<a href="'.get_site_url().'/login" class="typcn typcn-key-outline">Log in</a>';
```

Repeat the process and you'll end up with this :

```
<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    echo '<a href="'.get_site_url().'/login" class="typcn typcn-key-outline">Log in</a>';
    }
    else {
    echo '<a href="'.get_site_url().'/wp-login.php?action=logout" class="typcn typcn-key-outline">Log out</a>';
    } ?>
```

Hope the english isn't too bad

Comment: Why should OP use your answer? What did you change and why did OP's own code not work?

Comment: This worked great! and @Epodax , the reason his code works is because rather than put php inside of php he created a break where I wanted the code. It was creative and smart, like once you I saw it I face palmed so hard.

Comment: Well since it's was a basic concatenation, i thought it was a mistake and not a misunderstanding. if op wants explanation i can develop though :o

Comment: @コードバリノ I wasn't asking because I didn't understand, but it's a good idea to explain what you are doing, not only for OP but also for future visitors who visit this question.